# Change bibliography title align when using quotchap

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment, bibliographies, quotchap

I'm writing my Masters Thesis and I'm using `quotchap` package in my chapter tiles. However I want Bibliography title align at left instead of right like the other titles.

I've tried `\renewcommand{\bibname}{\leftline{References}}`. However, it alters the alignment in my table of contents and in the header of the bibliography pages.

Here goes a MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{Knu86,
    author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
    year = {1986},
    title = {The \TeX book},
  }
\end{filecontents}

\RequirePackage[times]{quotchap}
\definecolor{chaptergrey}{gray}{0.75}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{My chapter}

This is a reference \cite{Knu86}


\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{\leftline{Bibliography}} %this lines aligns left and shows how I want that bibliography title loks, but it changes the alignment in toc and in header of page 6. Comment to see how toc and the header of page 6 must look.
\bibliography{\jobname}
\newpage\clearpage\mbox{}\clearpage
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't have anything to do with [`quotchap`](http://ctan.org/pkg/quotchap). Instead, it's about expanded macros making their way into the ToC where they don't belong. Specifically `\leftline`...

Having said that, it's easier in this case to let them migrate into the ToC, but just make them do nothing when you call `\tableofcontents`. Here's an example of this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{Knu86,
    author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
    year = {1986},
    title = {The \TeX book},
  }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\renewcommand{\leftline}{}
\tableofcontents
\endgroup

\chapter{My chapter}

This is a reference \cite{Knu86}.

\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{\protect\leftline{Bibliography}}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Note how `\tableofcontents` is wrapped inside a `\begingroup`...`\endgroup` where `\leftline` is redefined to do nothing. Additionally, I've `\protect`ed `\leftline` in your `\bibname` redefinition, otherwise it's expanded when it's written to the `.toc`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It solves my problem in toc but it doesn't solve my problem with page headers. I had added this line `\newpage\clearpage\mbox{}\clearpage`
to show that the header in page 6 is not at right. In my thesis I have a bibliography with 3 pages, so I have that problem.