# Align "Bibliography" chapter in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies

In my Table of Contents, the *Bibliography* chapter is not aligned with the other chapters; in fact, it is slightly shifted to the left (please have a look at the image below). I would like it to be aligned with chapter names *Acknowledgements* and *Appendix*. How could I do that? I have already read this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194005/change-bibliography-title-align-when-using-quotchap) but I didn't find it useful for my issue.
[image]

---

Here I paste the commands used in the document for the unnumbered chapters:

#### Acknowledgements

```
\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}Acknowledgements}
```

#### Appendix

```
\chapter*{Appendix}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}Appendix}
```

#### Main

```
\input{acknowledgements.tex}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\input{appendix.tex}
```

Comment: What's with the "\numberline{}"? Have you tried deleting it? So instead of 

"\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}Appendix}"

it should say

"\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix}"

Comment: Deleting the `\numberline{}` will align everything under the "6" shown in the picture; which is an acceptable result for me, I did not consider it before. Thank you!     Anyway, if there is also a method for moving the chapter name "Bibliography" slightly towards the right, it would be nice to know it just for sake of completeness :)

Comment: Glad I could help. I those cases I am hacking a bit by simply adding a "~", which is basically a forced space character. In your case e.g. \chapter*{~Appendix}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{~Appendix}?

Comment: Thank you for the additional small tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's with the `\numberline{}`? Have you tried deleting it?

**Acknowledgements**

```
\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgements}
```

**Appendix**

```
\chapter*{Appendix}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix}
```

**Main**

```
\input{acknowledgements.tex}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\input{appendix.tex}
```

should do the trick.